# Find the width of an ellipse, on given Y position.

Tags: conic-sections

Look at picture below :

[image]

Q: I wonder what's the equation to find $L$ (the red line on `{x',y'}`, which `x'` will always be $0$), assuming if you don't know about the ellipse size.

Btw, I want to use the equation to programatically move the red line, on Y axis (bot->top), while also updating it's length ($L$) to match the ellipse on current Y position. Unfortunately, I'm not a math guy, so... Hahaha.

Thank you very much!

Comment: at least downvoter can explain why thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the ellipse is placed symmetrically about the $x$-axis. We can without loss of generality assume that it is also symmetrical about the $y$-axis. Then the equation of the ellipse is 
$$\frac{x^2}{r^2}+\frac{y^2}{R^2}=1.$$ 
It follows that at height $y$ above the $x$-axis, we have
$$L=2r\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{R^2}}.$$
You may prefer the equivalent
$$L=\frac{2r}{R}\sqrt{R^2-y^2}.$$